# 'Ubuntu Software' not asking for password and does nothing! Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: software-installation

Ubuntu Software had been installing programs OK but now when I click on Install all I get is, momemtarily, the box changes to 'Installing' with a small progress bar at the bottom but then goes back to 'Install' and nothing seems to happen - other than there is an icon in 'Launcher' bar with says 'Waiting to install' but nothing seems to happen.

I suspect this may have something to do with me unsuccessfully trying to install Google Earth, through a variety of methods, which resulted in a new icon appearing in the (in Windows) system tray (don't know what it's called in Ubuntu) which I think is 'notification' - red circle with horizontal white line. And I can't get rid of that as I don't know what I'm doing!

Guidance please,

Tim

Comment: Please open the terminal (ctrl+alt+t) and type `sudo apt update` (you will be asked for password) and if there's an error message, tell us the output.

Comment: Strange, I tried this yesterday and it tried but finished with an error message that, quite franjkly, I didn't understand.  However, this time round as follows -

Comment: And the output is too long to insert here - 15 Get and last line reads 'All packages are up-to-date.' but since you don't know what it 'got' I guess that is of no use to you!

Answer (score 0):

> I suspect this may have something to do with me unsuccessfully trying to install Google Earth

Your suspicion is probably correct.

Google has a wrong entry in its repository for `Google Earth`.
Because they removed the 32bit version, you need to tell your software manager to explicitly search for 64bit versions only.

This is a bug on Google side, and they fixed the same for Chrome already, but not for Earth.

As long as Google doesn't change that entry, you need to fix the entry manually now and **after every Update of Google Earth**. Luckily, this is quite easy.

Open a terminal and run the following command. (you will be asked for your password):

```
sudo sed -i 's/^deb http/deb [arch=amd64] http/' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-earth.list
```

After that, you can run `sudo apt update` or use the software center again without errors. And you can now also install Earth

---

Of course you can do that manually by opening the file with sudo rights (`gksudo /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-earth.list`) and add `[arch=amd64]` after `deb` so that it looks like this:

```
deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb/ stable main
```

Comment: Yes, I noticed that and read somewhere that I have to choose the 32bit and like you say it's not available - but I stupidly trusted Google!  I'm reluctant to try installing it again until I've cleared this 'notification' thing as trying to install BOINC Manager has also been sat 'Waiting to install' for the last couple of hours!